# R package management on Linux

Tags: linux, r, package, redhat

I have two accounts on a linux server, one with sudo power, one without.

When I install packages using the account with sudo power, it all works fine.

Then I logged in using another account without sudo power, it shows me the library not found.

Is there a way to solve this like changing the permission of the library? or install globally?

I have to use the account since the all the apps are running on it.

Comment: Can you indicate _where_ the packages are being installed when you use `sudo`?

Comment: I just checked, it installed to my personal directory

Comment: [1] "/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1"
[2] "/usr/lib64/R/library"                              
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"

Comment: so the packages installed to that local user directory. as `root` you can install into the system R packages directory or specify another accessible directory and just use that.

Comment: I just moved all the packages under the personal directory to usr/share and all the packages are working now. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after I checked my R packages location, I found all the new packages were installed under my personal directory. After I move it all to /usr/share/R/library it got solved.